# Error Exception: Indirect modification of overloaded property laravel

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I'm making an API that store a new version of an application. Here is my code:

```
  public function saveNewVersion() {
    $artifact_url = Input::get('url');
    $artifact_id = Input::get('id');
    $artifact_name = Input::get('name');
    $artifact_version = Input::get('version');

    $urls = explode('/', $artifact_url);

    //Exploding URL to dir
    $app_dir = "";

    for($i=5; $i<sizeof($urls); $i++)
        $app_dir .= $urls[$i] . '/';

    $app_dir .= $artifact_id;

    //Checking if the artifact_id exists in the database
    $app = Applications::where('app_dir', '=', $app_dir);

    if (!$app->count()) {
        //Save it as new application
        $new_app = new Applications();
        $new_app->application->name = $artifact_name;
        $new_app->app_dir = $app_dir;
        $new_app->save();

        $app_id = Applications::where('app_dir', '=', $app_dir)->first()->id;
    } else {
        $app_id = $app->first()->id;
        //Checking if the application name is not same as newrelic (Optional)
        if ($app->first()->application_name != $artifact_name) {
            $app = $app->first();
            $app->application_name = $artifact_name;
            $app->save();
        }
    }

    //check if the last version exists in the database
    $version = Versions::where('application_id', '=', $app_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    $lastVersion = $version->first()->version_number;

    if ($lastVersion != $artifact_version) {
        //check if the new version is exists before
        $flag = 0;
        $versions = Versions::where('application_id', '=', $app_id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        foreach ($versions as $item) {
            if ($item->version_number == $artifact_version) {
                $flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$flag) {
            $version = new Versions();
            $version->application_id = $app_id;
            $version->version_number = $artifact_version;
            $version->save();

            echo 'Application' . $app_id . 'has been updated to version ' . $artifact_version;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the API using postman, the API runs successfully and stores the new version of the application. But when I'm using CURL. I got `ErrorException: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Applications::$application` and it points to my `$new_app->save()` code.

Is there any problem with my code ? Or are there some parameters used in postman that make this error invisible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong here but it looks like the issue is the issue is here:

```
$new_app->application->name = $artifact_name;
```

I think it should be:

```
$new_app->application_name = $artifact_name;
```

based on the other code.